# Generic JSONParser.readValueAs for any object

Tags: apex, json

I have the following function:

```
public SObject PopulateSObjectFieldsForJSON(JSONParser parser)
{
   if (sobjectType == 'Queue_BH__c') {
        Queue_BH__c qbh = (Queue_BH__c)parser.readValueAs(Queue_BH__c.class);
        return qbh;
    } else if (sobjectType == 'Time_Zone__c') {
        Time_Zone__c tz = (Time_Zone__c)parser.readValueAs(Time_Zone__c.class);
        return tz;
}
```

This function receives JSONParse and returns an object with the fields from the JSON.
how can i make it generic so i dont have to handle any object separately like in the above?

Comment: FYI, usually the [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) class is easier to use than the JSONParser class; the JSON class has several deserialize options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `SObject`:

```
public SObject PopulateSObjectFieldsForJSON(JSONParser parser)
{
    return (SObject)parser.readValueAs(SObject.class);
}
```

In fact, you dont really need separate method. You can do:

```
Queue_BH__c qbh = (Queue_BH__c)parser.readValueAs(SObject.class);
```

And actually better to use below using [JSON class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) as you dont really need `parser`:

```
Queue_BH__c qbh = (Queue_BH__c)JSON.deserializeStrict(resp, SObject.class);
```